# Duration of censored events on lifelines package of survival analysis

Tags: python, survival-analysis, lifelines

I am working with [lifelines package](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) in python which is for survival analysis.
when I set different values on **duration_col** for censored events (the ones that have 0 on **event_col**), I get different results.

The fact is that censored events have no duration so theoretically it shouldn't change the result.

What should I set for the duration of censored values?

How does the algorithm consider the right censoring?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of lifelines.

> The fact is that censored events have no duration so theoretically it shouldn't change the result.

Censored events *do* have a duration¹. For example, I've been alive for 30 years, and I am still alive (that is, my death event is censored). So my life would have `duration=30, event=0`.

It might help to know what your application is for using survival analysis. Please let us know.

¹ I'm curious why you think censored events don't have a duration - was it unclear in some documentation you read?

Comment: Thank for your answer.
actually, the reason I thought the censored events don't have a duration Is that I supposed the duration of study is similar for all the individuals and the duration input of the function is actually "Life Duration". Now it's clear though.
About my application, actually my goal is to predict the time that a visitor comes back to a website. I'm using the CoxPHFitter since I want to consider other features of the visitor and the visit.

Comment: Another question I have is how to test the result in a proper way?
With the **scikit-learn’s API**, there is a predict function but I don't know how to do the same thing without it.
Something to get the closer time that the event will probably happen.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the docs here: https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Survival%20Regression.html#prediction and https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Compatibility%20with%20scikit-learn.html